# How to fix bundler "can't find version" upgrading Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to upgrade Nokogiri to version 1.7:

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.7'
```

but when I run:

```
bundle update --source nokogiri
```

I get:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.............
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
```

This is in my Gemfile:

```
    nokogiri (~> 1.7)

    activemerchant (~> 1.58.0) was resolved to 1.58.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)

    activemerchant (~> 1.58.0) was resolved to 1.58.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)

    capybara was resolved to 2.7.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)

    cucumber-rails was resolved to 1.4.3, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)

    haml-rails was resolved to 0.9.0, which depends on
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
        nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)

    haml-rails was resolved to 0.9.0, which depends on
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
        nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)

    rails (>= 4.2.6, ~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
      actionmailer (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
        actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
          rails-html-sanitizer (>= 1.0.2, ~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
            loofah (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
              nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)

    roo (~> 2.4.0) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1)

    roo-xls was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      nokogiri

    capybara was resolved to 2.7.0, which depends on
      xpath (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
        nokogiri (~> 1.3)
```

Does anyone have an idea why it can't find it? I see on rubygems.org that the current version is 1.7.1 as well as on github. Do I need to specify the github source?

Comment: Your caps lock key isn't working consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
haml-rails was resolved to 0.9.0, which depends on
  html2haml (>= 1.0.1) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
    nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
```

As you can see, `html2haml` depends on `nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)`, that is **not** `1.7`. You either need to update `html2haml` (so it dependency becomes `nokogiri (~> 1.6)`) or use `nokogiri, ~> 1.6`.

You could try deleting your `Gemfile.lock` file and running `bundle install` again, but i will only recommend doing it if you are not yet in production.

Answer (score 1):

I think other gems are depedent on Nokogiri, so
try `bundle update`.

`bundle update` will resolve a dependency tree and try and install versions that satisfy all the other gems dependencies.